# Mongo is not finding inserted data from Secondary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, amazon-sqs

My Mongo has **2 shards and each shard has 1 primary and 3 secondary**. 
My service is writing data to primary and there is another worker(SQS worker) is querying to mongo for recent inserted data. But many times it is not able to find that data. How to fix this error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Way too broad. This should be generally expected with secondary reads. If you want the latest data *"all of the time"* then you "should" be reading from the primary instead. *"I say we dust off and  read from the primary, It's the only way to be sure"*

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I have one more doubt, is there any possibility it may happens with primary . I am writing to Primary and if tries to read same from primary within milliseconds, Can it return not find?

Comment: Like I said, the case is quite broad. One driving factor will always be the write concern used. With default write concern, writes to the primary are always acknowledged. However you are allowed to change that for a *"fire and forget"* behavior, is you so choose. Also nothing stopping a read in a separate process to happen before the write is acknowledged. Generally speaking, leave the write concern alone and always read from the primary unless you specifically know exactly what you are doing, and the effects are intended.

Comment: @NeilLunn not 100% true. The default write concern in MongoDB is, as you say, `acknowledge`, but this _does not_ guarantee that the *read* will see the changes that the *write* made (confusing, I know). To achieve this, you should use the `journaled` write concern.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your reading plays the trick, there is always a delay in updating the data from primary to all secondary nodes. Your scenario might be happening when you have write some data in primary and before the secondary gets the updated data, you are trying to reading it from the secondary.

There is a bunch of documentation related to configuring your secondary nodes. Please go thru them. Please see below some of the references related to replication.

Please check on the write concern for better results.

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/configure-replica-set-secondary-sync-target/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/